# When making a network request to my external IP, does traffic leave the intranet?

Tags: networking, router

Let's say I have a router and my computer connected to its network. The router is configured to forward incoming traffic on port `80` to my computer. The networks *external* IP is `1.2.3.4`.

When I make the request `http://1.2.3.4:80`, does the router send the request to my ISP or is the router aware of its external IP and directly redirects the traffic back to my computer?